# How do I interlace element from an array in ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays

So the goal is to combine two arrays that contain sentences, in a new array that would have to sentences interchanged.

Something along the lines of:

```
array_1 = ['1','2','3']

array_2 = ['a','b','c']

new_array = ['1','a','2','b','3','c']
```

Would appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

zip and flatten

```
array_1.zip(array_2).flatten(1)
```

Comment: flatten(1) is conceptually more exact.

Comment: I agree. `flatten!` will not change anything here. Use `flatten`. Editing answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

Just to be different...

```
[array_1, array_2].transpose.flatten
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Array.zip`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-zip):

```
 array_1.zip(array_2)

irb(main):163:0> array_1.zip(array_2)
[
    [0] [
        [0] "1",
        [1] "a"
    ],
    [1] [
        [0] "2",
        [1] "b"
    ],
    [2] [
        [0] "3",
        [1] "c"
    ]
]
```

Flatten if you want to get rid of the embedded arrays.